# When trying to connect to a remote Oracle database with Django I get an odd error

Tags: python, django, oracle

I'm using Python 2.6 and Django 1.2.3 Final.

Whenever I try to run 'inspectdb' or any other action that would connect to this remote Oracle database, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/var/www/local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/var/www/local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/www/local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/var/www/local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 22, in handle_noargs
    for line in self.handle_inspection(options):
  File "/var/www/local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 32, in handle_inspection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/var/www/local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 75, in cursor
    cursor = self._cursor()
  File "/var/www/local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 361, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(conn_string, **self.settings_dict['OPTIONS'])
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12505
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you get a cryptic error message, Search The Fantastic Web. In this case, the software is sufficiently professionally organised as to have distinct error message numbers and an error message manual. All you need to do is `google("ORA-12505")`

Comment: I understand, but the answer seems just as cryptic: http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/oracle/ORA12505.htm

Comment: @user28360: That's just one of the MANY google responses, and it's from a former Oracle user. The impression I got is that either your settings are wrong, or the remote database was not fully operational at the time you tried. In either case a phone call to the helpdesk seems indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you did a mistake in your settings.py file DB connection parameters. Review them to be sure that everything is correct.

http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/oracle/ORA12505.htm